# Flex - Using the vanilla preloader to load additional assets?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I have a Flex application that automatically loads the SWF and it's contents and displays the default progress bar like in all Flex apps. Currently I have a class in the application using a Loader instance to load an external bitmap to be added to the stage/canvas. I'd like to handle the loading of this bitmap in the Flex default preloader and get rid of the Loader instance entirely.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own implementation of mx.preloaders.DownloadProgressBar and set it as the preloader in your main application file.

```
<mx:Application ... preloader="com.domain.MyCustomPreloader"/>
```